# JOINS And Multi-Table Queries

Tags: sql

Write a query that provides the following information for all books published by Taylor & Wells and Classics4you: The book title, named as "Book"; the book price, named as "Price"; the number of pages, named as "Pages"; and finally, the author's surname, named as "Author". Order the listing by the book's title, alphabetically.

I have tried a query with different options already.

```
SELECT title AS "Book", price AS "Price", pages AS "Pages",
       surname AS "Author" 
from (
   book INNER JOIN author ON author.authorid=book.authorid
) INNER JOIN publisher ON publisher.publisherid=book.publisherid
where publisher.name = ' Classics4you' 
AND publisher.name='Taylor & Wells'
GROUP BY title, price, pages, surname, name
ORDER BY title;
```

Your result

```
Book    Price   Pages   Author
```

Expected result

```
Book    Price   Pages   Author
My life as I see it 55.2    782 Weinstein-Welle
The Crime that never was    16.4    555 Adams
The Ghost of the Moor   23.1    310 Adams
The Winter Everlasting  46.8    1156    Weinstein-Welle
Three Bearded Men and the Sea   21.8    333 Adams
Upside-down and other children's stories    20.8    245 Weinstein-Welle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line `(book INNER JOIN author ON author.authorid=book.authorid)`, there is an incorrect syntax that does not exists in SQL. You should use the correct syntax like bellow:

```
SELECT 
title AS "Book", 
price AS "Price", 
pages AS "Pages", 
surname AS "Author" 
FROM book 
INNER JOIN author ON author.authorid=book.authorid
INNER JOIN publisher ON publisher.publisherid=book.publisherid
where publisher.name = ' Classics4you' 
OR publisher.name='Taylor & Wells'
GROUP BY title, price, pages, surname, name
ORDER BY title
```

Comment: Name can't be Classics **and** Taylor. Must be **or**. Or, use **in**. Also, what is the purpose of group by here?

Comment: I only correct the syntax. But that point is correct, that syntax does not necessary use the group by.